# Unity 2D function gameObject.transform.Translate(...) does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
    //Translation$
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
    {
        gameObject.transform.Translate (-speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (localScale.x > 0)
        {
            localScale.x *= -1.0f;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        gameObject.transform.Translate (speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (localScale.x < 0)
        {
            localScale.x *= -1.0f;
        }
    }
    transform.localScale = localScale;
```

i use this to move my character, but it doesnot work, someone help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does *doesnot work* mean? do you need to assign the translate value to something? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: What is `speed` set as? If it's `Vector3.zero` then it's not going to go anywhere.

Comment: speed > 0, but the character does not move

Comment: @Sayse, the character must move with those code, but he doesn't

Comment: Is this code in update? Is this monobehaviour attached to gameobject? Is this monobehaviour active, and is the gameobject? Do the "if" conditions return true when you expect them true? Does the code move the character if you remove the conditions? There's a ton of questions that you could've asked and found out an answer before asking the community. And finally, why the hell do you assign the negative scale to the transform?